# Changing data type from DATE to CHAR(10) with a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to alter the date type in a database that has 40 tables from `DATE` type to `CHAR(10)` type, *without* opening the tables and manipulating them in Management Studio. i.e. only with a script/query.

I want to alter all columns of that type in any table in this database.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to say that you want to alter the data type of a column from DATE to CHAR(10) in a script and not in Management Studio? For a single column, all columns in a single table, all columns of all tables in your database? It's not very clear, so please try to get more details. Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Marian ,I explain more and edit my question.I can do it for one table but I don't know how do it for all (or many) tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A piece of code that does what you want is:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @crlf char(2) = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10);

select @sql = isnull(@sql, '') + 'alter table ' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + c.TABLE_NAME + ' alter column ' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' CHAR(10)' + 
    + case when c.IS_NULLABLE = 'YES' then ' NULL;' else ';' end + @crlf
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
where DATA_TYPE = 'date'

print @sql;
-- exec sp_executesql @sql --execute only after inspection!
```

But I would like to stress that you shouldn't normally do it on a system (except for dev/test purposes), because if it is Date information that you're using, you should be using the proper data type and avoid any other unnecessary cast.

Comment: ,Don't worry!I test this snippet code on a test DB at first time, then use it.BTW thanks so much.;)